# Function using foldr is too eager

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have a little alternative implementation of `groupBy`, which is more useful to me than the version in `Data.List`, because it doesn't require the test to be an equivalence relation:

```
groupBy' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy' f = foldr step []
    where step x [] = [[x]]
          step x (xs:xss)
              | x `f` head xs = (x:xs):xss
              | otherwise     = [x]:xs:xss
```

However, it's too eager and won't start computing for inputs like `groupBy' (<) [1,2,3,2,3,4,1,undefined]`. I have read the [HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Maintaining_laziness) and [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness) articles which explain why certain things, like pattern matches, can make functions less lazy, and I think I understand most of the examples given there. Still, I don't understand why this function can't start producing output until it hits the `undefined`. Are the pattern matches causing this behavior?

Since I have just read those articles, it's maybe lack of experience that makes me fail to apply what I read there to my example code. So, how could this particular implementation be changed in order to behave more lazily?

Comment: Where is constraint `Ord a` used?

Comment: Tsuyoshi, it can be left out. I guess it is just an artifact from before I made it take a comparison function. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key problem is that you know that `step x xss` will always produce a result of the form `(x:_):_`, but you are "hiding" this behind the pattern matches, so Haskell is forced to evaluate those first to determine which case of `step` to choose before it even sees those constructors.

In general, for `foldr f x` to be able to produce any output before reaching the end of the list, `f` must be able to produce some output before examining its second argument.

We can fix this by splitting `step` into two, so that we can produce the two `(:)` constructors before doing the pattern matching on the second argument.

```
groupBy' f = foldr step []
  where step x xss = let (ys, yss) = step' x xss in (x:ys):yss
        step' x [] = ([], [])
        step' x (xs:xss) | f x (head xs) = (xs, xss)
                         | otherwise     = ([], xs:xss)
```

This is about as lazy as you can get it.

```
*Main> groupBy' (<) [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, undefined]
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I already assumed that this was a problem with the pattern matching, but I wasn't sure and failed to apply the examples I had seen from the two linked articles to my example. (Instead I tried to play around with lazy pattern matches in vain, half-knowing it wouldn't work). Do you maybe know other sources I could read to learn about this, maybe with examples a little more complex than in the two articles, like this one? Or is this just something you learn by doing?

Comment: @danlei: The [WikiBooks page on denotational semantics](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics) is quite useful, but a lot also comes from practice.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try. I remember skimming it some time ago – Maybe it's time for me to work through it thoroughly.

Answer (score 4):

`foldr step [] [1,2,3,...]` will expand to `step 1 (foldr step [] [2,3])`. Now `step` needs to decide whether to go in its first case or the second. For that it needs to know whether `foldr step [] [2,3,...]` evaluates to an empty list. For that it needs to know whether `step 2 (foldr step [] [3,...])` returns the empty list (which it never will, but Haskell does not know that). This goes on until the end of the list is reached (and if the list doesn't have an end, it goes on forever).

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult for me to understand what your code will do when `f` is not an equivalence relation, but I guess that you want something like the following code:

```
groupBy' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy' f [] = []
groupBy' f [x] = [[x]]
groupBy' f (x : xs)
  | x `f` head xs = (x : head l) : tail l
  | otherwise = [x] : l
  where
    l = groupBy' f xs
```

or equivalently without using `head` or `tail`:

```
groupBy' :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy' f [] = []
groupBy' f (x : xs) = hd : tl
  where
    (hd, tl) = go x xs
    go x [] = ([x], [])
    go x xs@(x' : xs')
      | x `f` x' = (x : hd', tl')
      | otherwise = ([x], hd' : tl')
      where
        (hd', tl') = go x' xs'
```

Comment: Thanks, those implementations do the job, but you fail to explain what breaks laziness for the particular implementation in my question, and what to do about it. That's what I'm interested in.  About the equivalence relation question: If you use `(<)` or `(<=)`, which is not an equivalence relation, but a partial order, it would compute sublists in which each element is smaller (or equals) than the one following it (also called "runs").